# python how to extract particular data in a line which start from different characters

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
path=os.getcwd()
list_dir=os.listdir(path+'//Osativa')
if not os.path.exists('results'):
    os.makedirs('results')
fo1=open('./results/annotation.txt','w')
f1=open(path+'//CLEAN FILE.csv').readlines()
f2=open(path+'//Osativa//Osativa_323_v7.0.annotation_info.txt').readlines()
f02=open('./results/PF.txt','w')
#num=0
for line in f1:
    locus_id=line.split(',')[1]
    if locus_id.startswith('LOC'):
        #num +=1
        #print(num)
        #print (locus_id)
        #num1=0
        for line1 in f2:
            if locus_id==line1.split()[1]:
                #num1+=1
                #print (num1)
                #print locus_id
                transcript=line1.split()[2]
                if transcript.startswith('LOC'):
                    #print (locus_id+'\t'+transcript)
                    for i in line1.split():
                        if i.startswith('PF'):
                            #print (locus_id+'\t'+transcript+'\t'+i)
                            break
                    else:
                            #print(locus_id+'\t'+transcript+'\t'+'\t')
                            for j in line1.split():
                                if j.startswith('PTHR'):
                                    print (j)
                                    break
                            else:
                                print ('\t')
```

I didn't get values which start with 'PTHR'. 
And if i want to get the output into separate files rather than printing them what should I do ? Here 'j' is id starts from PTHR.
Please anyone can show me what's wrong with this script ?

```
f1 sample input:
```

5.2,LOC_Os01g07070,Os01g0164400,osRBD2b,1,f,3321774,3326179,,,
5.2,LOC_Os05g51480,Os05g0592400,osDBP2a,5,f,29449210,29457409,,,
5.2,LOC_Os07g12490,Os07g0227400,osRBD1b,7,f,7119724,7125463,,,

```
f2 sample input:
```

33123472        LOC_Os01g15010  LOC_Os01g15010.1        LOC_Os01g15010.1        PF08477 PTHR11711,PTHR11711:SF203      KOG0077         K07953  GO:0007264,GO:0005525   AT4G02080.1     ASAR1,ATSAR2,ATSARA1C,SAR2      secretion-associated RAS super family 2
33122156        LOC_Os01g15020  LOC_Os01g15020.1        LOC_Os01g15020.1        PF00400 PTHR22847,PTHR22847:SF424       KOG0266                 GO:0005515      AT3G16830.1     TPR2    TOPLESS-related 2
33122157        LOC_Os01g15020  LOC_Os01g15020.2        LOC_Os01g15020.2        PF00400 PTHR22847,PTHR22847:SF424       KOG0266                 GO:0005515      AT3G16830.1     TPR2    TOPLESS-related 2
33121795        LOC_Os01g15029  LOC_Os01g15029.1        LOC_Os01g15029.1                                5.2.1.8                 AT3G66654.3             Cyclophilin-like peptidyl-prolyl cis-trans isomerase family protein

I match LOC_id of f1 with LOC_id of f2. Then I extract its particular data such as PF id, PTHR id etc.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, i.e. what you'd expect to see in `f1` and `f2`? Also, what do you expect/hope to see in `print (j)`?

Comment: Sure. I already edit my question. so can you have a look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the input data you've provided and adding in an entry that actually matches (last row in `f2`), I've used the following code which printed the match:

```
f1 = [ 
    "5.2,LOC_Os01g07070,Os01g0164400,osRBD2b,1,f,3321774,3326179,,,", 
    "5.2,LOC_Os05g51480,Os05g0592400,osDBP2a,5,f,29449210,29457409,,,",
    "5.2,LOC_Os07g12490,Os07g0227400,osRBD1b,7,f,7119724,7125463,,,",
]

f2 = [ 
    "33123472 LOC_Os01g15010 LOC_Os01g15010.1 LOC_Os01g15010.1 PF08477 PTHR11711,PTHR11711:SF203 KOG0077 K07953 GO:0007264,GO:0005525 AT4G02080.1 ASAR1,ATSAR2,ATSARA1C,SAR2 secretion-associated RAS super family 2",
    "33122156 LOC_Os01g15020 LOC_Os01g15020.1 LOC_Os01g15020.1 PF00400 PTHR22847,PTHR22847:SF424 KOG0266 GO:0005515 AT3G16830.1 TPR2 TOPLESS-related 2",
    "33122157 LOC_Os01g15020 LOC_Os01g15020.2 LOC_Os01g15020.2 PF00400 PTHR22847,PTHR22847:SF424 KOG0266 GO:0005515 AT3G16830.1 TPR2 TOPLESS-related 2",
    "33121795 LOC_Os01g15029 LOC_Os01g15029.1 LOC_Os01g15029.1 5.2.1.8 AT3G66654.3 Cyclophilin-like peptidyl-prolyl cis-trans isomerase family protein",
    "33121795 LOC_Os07g12490 LOC_Os01g15029.1 LOC_Os01g15029.1 5.2.1.8 PTHR22847,PTHR22847:SF424 AT3G66654.3 Cyclophilin-like peptidyl-prolyl cis-trans isomerase family protein",
]


for info in f1:
    locus_id = info.split(',')[1]
    if not locus_id.startswith("LOC"):
        continue

    for detail in f2:
        split_detail = detail.split()
        if locus_id != split_detail[1]:
            continue

        if not split_detail[2].startswith("LOC"):
            continue

        for element in split_detail:
            if element[:4].upper() == "PTHR":
                print(element)
```

Running this code, I get the following output printed to my screen:

```
PTHR22847,PTHR22847:SF424
```

I've renamed some variables in the script and simplified the conditionals to decrease the maximum indentation of your nested loops and clarify the code.

If you want to write the data to a file rather than print it to the screen, I would use the following:

```
# ====
# DEFINITIONS OF f1 and f2
# ====

f_out = open("output.txt", "w")

for info in f1: 
    locus_id = info.split(',')[1]
    if not locus_id.startswith("LOC"):
        continue

    for detail in f2: 
        split_detail = detail.split()
        if locus_id != split_detail[1]:
            continue

        if not split_detail[2].startswith("LOC"):
            continue

        for element in split_detail:
            if element[:4].upper() == "PTHR":
                f_out.write(element + "\n")

f_out.close()
```